# Cannot increase disk space of a esxi VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, hypervisor, datastore

I wanted to increase the disk space of a VM in my VMware server esxi.

I deleted a snapshot that was in the VM, but I canceled this operation unintentionally.

Now, I can't see the snapshot in snapshot manager, and I can't increase the disk space

This is the current storage of VM in datastore

[storage vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Ph2.png)

Any idea to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've screwed that VM to be honest - what I'd do is shutdown this VM, create a new temporary Linux VM, add the vmdk from this broken VM as a second disk to the temporary VM, create a new identically-sized vmdk and add this to the temporary VM then 'dd' the contents of 'disk 2' to 'disk 3', shut the temporary VM down, disconnect the second and third disks then use the third disk as the primary disk for a new, hopefully working, VM and once it's settled down then try extending the disk, rescan the scsi bus, update the partition and resize the filesystem.

Oh and learn to not use snaps for very long or stop their deletion :)